# How to combine all textures in to a single texture (glb export)

Tags: texturing

I am a developer and recently picked up a WebXR project and where they're working with the .glb file format.

I received a textured model with a separate baked lightmap texture. I can combine the lightmap with the existing textures using a MixRGB node, however, the new texture doesn't export to the .glb export.

How can I combine multiple textures when exporting to glb?

Thanks in advance,
Mark